# Fargo SDK Laminate an IDcard

Tags: c#, .net, printing, id-card

I am developing an IDcard printing Application which uses `Fargo SDK` to send an IDcard to `FARGO DTC-4500` printer to be printed. After the IDcard gets printed i want to issue a command to `Laminate` the IDcard which is just printed, But I Could not find a method in the SDK to issue the `Lamination process command`.

Can anyone please help me with this how to laminate an IDcard after its printed using `FARGO SDK` and `FARGO DTC-4500` printer?
I am using the `.NET` version of `FARGO SDK`.

I have created a `PrintJob` object , I have added and positioned all the texts and images that should be printed on the front and backside of the card using `PrintJob.AddPrintImageElement` and `PrintJob.AddPrintTextElement` and then i have called the `PrintJob.DoPrint()` method to initiate the printing process. now my question is does this method calls the lamination process itself automatically? or is there another method to be called for lamination? or the lamination can be done directly using buttons on the printer?

Comment: Please show us show of your code and tell us what exactly (in code) you have tried.

Comment: I have created a `PrintJob` object , I have added and positioned all the texts and images that should be printed on the front and backside of the card using `PrintJob.AddPrintImageElement` and `PrintJob.AddPrintTextElement` and then i have called the `PrintJob.DoPrint()` method to initiate the printing process. now my question is does this method calls the lamination process itself automatically? or is there another method to be called for lamination? or the lamination can be done directly using buttons on the printer?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the aforementioned information (the one you have in the comment) there.